# How to check if file exist in zip archive

Tags: php, zip

i have zip archive and after extract him i need to check if moduleConfig.xml exist inside zip archive. How i can do that.

I try this

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE )
{
    if(file_exists($zip->getFromName('moduleConfig.xml')))
    {
        echo "Config exists";
        // Do somthing
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Failed code:'. $res;
}
```

Comment: you tried this, but it did what instead?

Comment: I try this and this dont work. I dont understand ur question.

Answer (score 11):

It should be like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE )
{
    if ($zip->locateName('moduleConfig.xml') !== false)
    {
    echo "Config exists";
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Failed code:'. $res;
}
```

Comment: Note: You should check it using `!== false` because it can return `0` when file exists. so `if ( $zip->locateName('file.xml') ) {...}` doesn't works correctly. [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.locatename.php)

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
if ($zip->locateName('moduleConfig.xml') !== false)
{
    echo "Config exists";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `getFromName`

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        if($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE )
        {
            if($zip->getFromName('moduleConfig.xml') != false)
            {
                echo "Config exists";
                // Do somthing
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Failed code:'. $res;
        }
```